# Power to the home in the UK

Tags: power, ac, phase

We have a question about the power available to the home in the UK.
Our product draws a fair amount of current, so we have (so far) designed it to be powered by ~230vac single phase at 48A **OR** ~230vac 3 phase, 16A for each phase.
We bought **IEC 60364-1** and read section **312.1.1 Current-carrying conductors in a.c. circuits.**
We understand that we may encounter:
1 phase 2 wire, 1 phase 3 wire, 2 phase 3 wire, 3 phase 3 wire or 3 phase 4 wire.
Our specific question is what kind of coverage will each of these two options give us in the UK (or the continent)

Comment: I did hear that electricity in rural areas is single phase. I took the implication that in cities it might be 3-phase, but with residents in apartments getting access to one phase of it. I did a quick check to see if there were ready demographics (google) and didn't see anything useful, though. Hopefully, someone will find a report of some kind for you. [When searching for UK-specifics, Marmite always pops to mind. I have to stop my fingers from adding that to the search. ;) ]

Comment: Is your product going to be hard-wired? I don't think you'll find many (if any) homes have a socket capable of delivering 48A.

Comment: It's common for instant heat electric showers in the 8 to 11kw range (32 to 44A at 240v single phase) to be hard-wired into their own breaker directly from the company fuse. 3 phase is commonly available to light industry and up, not to domestic users.

Comment: Many residential properties have single phase from 40 to 80A feed, some larger/older houses might have 3 phase but perhaps limited to 30 A.  Even if you have enough breaker current you may find that the load from the rest of the property will not leave you enough during consumption periods.  The stored energy is one of those valuable bonuses of water heaters, if your product competes with that benefit it will have to be cheaper or better in other respects.  Much of industrialised Europe has similar residential limits some places have less.

Answer (score 2):

Note that he three phase is 230V phase to neutral, 400V phase to phase.

The lions share of UK domestic property is single phase, 230V Phase to Neutral (Usually closer to 240V in reality), and for 40A you would be needing a special purpose circuit installing, you will not (with the exception of some folks who run big machines) see a domestic outlet bigger then 13A (~3kW), but a special purpose circuit can be installed by an electrician.

The common connectors used for such things are Blue 32A or 63A IEC 60309 connectors, in 2 pole plus earth 6H configuration, but they are not something you usually see in domestic situations (I have a 32A example installed in the shed for a welder).

Most UK housing is has an incoming supply fused at either 60 or 100A, with three phase very much the exception rather then the rule, assume single phase is what will be available unless you are selling to light industry.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK the most common supply is either Single Phase or 3 phase.

Single Phase is 240V phase to neutral and is found in all homes, offices and light industrial property. All outlets are 3 pin, Live, Neutral and Earth. Single Phase outlets over 13A will be round blue.

Common outlets are the 'standard' 3 pin BS 1363 wall socket and the Industrial IEC 60309 Blue P+N+E round sockets in 16A, 32A and 64A variants.

3 Phase is usually only installed in larger industrial property and will use the Red round IEC 60309 outlets which will be 4 or 5 pin 3P+E or 3P+N+E.

Sometimes 3 phase will be physically in the cable at the meter in UK homes but it is never in the distribution board. There maybe an exception in very large manor houses, stately homes etc. Sometimes it may also be installed if the home owner requires it for large machinery etc (A friend of mine had it installed to run lathes and milling machines in his garage) but it is very rare.

2 Phase is rare, it was usually used for older machinery and is never installed in a new installations now, sometimes very large homes or commercial property will be supplied with two phases but they will be treated as two separate single phase supplies where each single phase doesn't have the required current capacity.

So in summary you will only really encounter:

Single Phase 3Pin

3Phase 4pin

3Phase 5pin

In outlet sizes of 13A, 16A, 32A, 64A and 125A.

Anything else is only used in specialist applications.